# facebook WebDriverAgent usb support

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, webdriver, automated-tests

I have been trying to use this facebook webdriver
https://github.com/facebook/WebDriverAgent

for iOS test automation, I've been using it successfully over wifi but i can't get it working over USB and I would really need it in my project.

logs say when to run the driver that it's listening on usb on localhost:8100 but that url wont respond if I try to send request or start the inspector.

the peertalk they mentioned  they have used for implementing. Works perfectly when  I tried to run their example.

according to code here:

https://github.com/facebook/WebDriverAgent/blob/master/WebDriverAgentLib/Routing/FBWebServer.m#L68

It should start the usb driver too and I have forced the shouldListenOnUSB to true.

```
- (void)startServing
{
  [FBLogger logFmt:@"Built at %s %s", __DATE__, __TIME__];
  self.exceptionHandler = [FBExceptionHandler new];
  [self startHTTPServer];
  if (FBConfiguration.shouldListenOnUSB) {
    [self startUSBServer];
  }
  [[NSRunLoop mainRunLoop] run];
}
```

help to get usb support work would be nice thankyou in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK so  I found a solution and want to share it  you need to forward the . webdriver traffic to local host port.  You  can do it forexample with

https://github.com/imkira/mobiledevice

install it with brew

put wda running then just

```
mobiledevice tunnel 8080 8100
```

now inspector is working in address

http://localhost:8080/inspector